# Largest possible prime factor for given $k$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, totient-function, divisor-sum

Let $k$ be a positive integer.

> What is the largest possible prime factor of a squarefree positive integer $\ n\ $ with $\ \omega(n)=k\ $ (That is, it has exactly $\ k\ $ prime factors) satisfying the condition $\ \varphi(n)\mid \sigma(n)\ $ , where $\ \varphi(n)\ $ is the totient-function and $\ \sigma(n)\ $ the divisor-sum function , assuming that such a positive integer $\ n\ $ exists at all ?

- For $k=1$ , the solutions are $2$ and $3$ , hence the largest prime factor is $3$.
- For $k=2$ , the solutions are $6,14,15,35$ , hence the largest prime factor is $7$.
- For $k=3$ , the largest prime factor seems to be $19$ , for example for $n=5\cdot 11\cdot 19$
- For $k=4$ , the lagest prime factor seems to be $127$ , for example for $n=5\cdot 13\cdot 17\cdot 127$

[here](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000003133271364) is a solution with $68$ prime factors , the largest being the $13$ digit prime $5135147640209$ , hence for $k=68$ we have at least this prime factor as the largest possible.

We call $\ p(k)\ $ the largest prime factor , if a solution exists (which I assume to be the case, but I have no proof). If there is no efficient way to determine $\ p(k)\ $, is there at least a good upper bound ?

Comment: So to spell out: Let $k$ be given. Then for $k$ primes $p_1<\cdots <p_k$ such that 
$$\prod_{i=1}^k(p_i-1) \mid \prod_{i=1}^k(p_i+1),$$
we want to establish a bound on $p_k$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Exactly

Comment: $p(5)\ge 13\ 121$ , as the solution $n=3\cdot 7\cdot 19\cdot 163\cdot 13121$ shows.

Comment: $p(6)\ge 1\ 806\ 461$ , as the solution $n=3\cdot 7\cdot 19\cdot 163\cdot 13217\cdot 1806461$ shows.

Comment: @Peter, Suppose we have:

$$\huge\Pi^k_{i=1}(p_i+1)=m\cdot\huge\Pi^k_{i=1}(p_i-1)$$

For $k=2$:

$(n, m)=(6, 6),(14, 4), (15, 3), (35, 2)$

For $k=3$:

$(n, m)=(1045, 2)$

For $k=4$:

$(n, m)=(96768, 2)$

For $k=68$ m can be found. I do not see any reason for why this equation must have limited solutions. I guess there exist numbers for $k>68$, also m has a range and a limit.

Comment: @sirous I still think that for a given $k$, the largest prime factor is limited, but the largest possible factor soon "explodes". For $k=12$ , I could construct a solution having already a $198$-digit prime factor. If we fix $j$ of the $k$ prime factors, the smallest value of the remaining $k-j$ prime factors can be bounded from above, therefore there should be finite many solutions for every $k$.